# Logo critique for my gaming studio

Tags: logo, critique

I'd like some help on a logo design I have going for my gaming studio - something about this doesn't feel like a cohesive whole. My instinct is to look for a font that matches the aesthetic of the mark but any additional pointers are welcome.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Assuming BAD is not a bath, make it look bad. An example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDAzC.png

Comment: You have a conflation problem on upper right edge of pictogram. Also consider withe instead of gray. The gay can be problematic in any printed material you may need.